# regex to match word separated by characters and enclosed by xml tags

Tags: regex, character, delimited

I have been trying to build a regex to do the following:

Look for the word "alphabet" enclosed in xml tags , search would match the following:

```
<hw>Al"pha*bet</hw>
<hw>Al"pha*be`t</hw>        
<hw>alphabet</hw>    
<hw>al*pha*bet</hw>        
<hw>al"pha"b"et</hw>
```

The word can be separated by 3 special chars: "  *  `, the search would have to have case-insensitive. Can you please help me out by building a regex that would specifically search for the word alphabet with or without any of the special chars mentioned above.

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind?  Note that my first thought would be to pull the tagged substrings, eliminate those characters then match but It may not be ideal depending on your language or data set.

Comment: yeah..best way to go about this sort of depends on what language and how you are getting the example data to begin with. For instance, if you are using an xml parser class (with for instance php) then you can grab the tags easy enough with prefab functions.  But even if it were straight up scraping raw content using pure regex, it would still be "cleaner" to strip out the special chars and then compare to "alphabet"...esp since I have a sneaking suspicion "alphabet" is just an example word and you will be applying this to any word...

Comment: Example strings that you will match on, language? What do you want to match: The word, the lines, the tags (with content), or a full block such as above?

Comment: php or C, I remember seeing in perl something like this, but I am not going to use perl: $astring =~ s/["*`]//g;
  $astring =~ s/&Verbar;//g;
  
  if ($astring =~ /$pattern/i)

Answer (score 2):

This will work with the caveat that regex shouldn't be used to parse xml/html, etc..

Its always easier to capture simple samples, then sub-process them in a callback.
In this case capture ([alphabet"*`,]+), then strip out the unwanted characters, then do a comparison.

A Perl sample, the concept is the same for Perl/PHP/C# etc...

```
$sample = '
  <hw>Al"pha*bet</hw>
  <hw>Al"pha*be`t</hw>        
  <hw>alphabet</hw>    
  <hw>al*pha*bet</hw>        
  <hw>al"pha"b"et</hw>
';

$specialword = 'alphabet';
$uc_specialword = uc( $specialword );

while ($sample =~ m{<([A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*)(?:\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*(?<!/)>([$specialword"*`,]+)</\1\s*>}isg)
{
    ($matchstr, $checkstr) = ($&, $2);
    $checkstr =~ s/["*`,]//g;
    if (uc($checkstr) eq $uc_specialword) {
       print "Found '$checkstr' in '$matchstr'\n";
    } 
}
```

Expanded regex:

```
m{   # Regex delim
<                         # Open tag
  ([A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*)                  # Capture 1, the tag name
  (?:\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*  # optional attr/val pairs
  (?<!/)
>
([alphabet"*`,]+)        # Capture 2, class of special characters allowed, 'alphabet' plus "*`,
</\1\s*>                 # Close tag, backref to tag name (group 1)

}xisg  # Regex delim. Options: expanded, case insensitive, single line, global
```

Output:

```
Found 'Alphabet' in '<hw>Al"pha*bet</hw>'
Found 'Alphabet' in '<hw>Al"pha*be`t</hw>'
Found 'alphabet' in '<hw>alphabet</hw>'
Found 'alphabet' in '<hw>al*pha*bet</hw>'
Found 'alphabet' in '<hw>al"pha"b"et</hw>'
```

**PHP example's**

Using `preg_match()` can be found here http://www.ideone.com/8EBpx

```
<?php

  $sample = '
    <hw>Al"pha*bet</hw>
    <hw>Al"pha*be`t</hw>        
    <hw>alphabet</hw>    
    <hw>al*pha*bet</hw>        
    <hw>al"pha"b"et</hw>
  ';

  $specialword = 'alphabet';
  $uc_specialword = strtoupper( $specialword );
  $regex = '~<([A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*)(?:\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*(?<!/)>([' . $specialword. '"*`,]+)</\1\s*>~xis';
  $pos = 0;

  while ( preg_match($regex, $sample, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos) )
  {
     $matchstr = $matches[0][0];
     $checkstr = $matches[2][0];

     $checkstr = preg_replace( '/[" * `,]/', "", $checkstr);
     if ( strtoupper( $checkstr ) == $uc_specialword )
         print "Found '$checkstr' in '$matchstr'\n";

     $pos = $matches[0][1] + strlen( $matchstr );
  }

?>
```

Using `preg_match_all()` can be found here http://www.ideone.com/C6HeT

```
<?php

  $sample = '
    <hw>Al"pha*bet</hw>
    <hw>Al"pha*be`t</hw>        
    <hw>alphabet</hw>    
    <hw>al*pha*bet</hw>        
    <hw>al"pha"b"et</hw>
  ';

  $specialword = 'alphabet';
  $uc_specialword = strtoupper( $specialword );
  $regex = '~<([A-Za-z_:][\w:.-]*)(?:\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*(?<!/)>([' . $specialword. '"*`,]+)</\1\s*>~xis';

  preg_match_all($regex, $sample, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

  foreach ($matches as $match)
  {
     $matchstr = $match[0];
     $checkstr = $match[2];

     $checkstr = preg_replace( '/[" * `,]/', "", $checkstr);
     if ( strtoupper( $checkstr ) == $uc_specialword )
         print "Found '$checkstr' in '$matchstr'\n";
  }

?>
```

Comment: $astring =~ s/["*`]//g;
$astring =~ s/&Verbar;//g;
if ($astring =~ /$pattern/i)

what about that ? where $pattern is "<hw>alphabet</hw>" ? Is there an easier way to tranlsate that to C or PHP ? 

thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: @Alex - added some php examples.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
a([`"\*])*l([`"\*])*p([`"\*])*h([`"\*])*a([`"\*])*b([`"\*])*e([`"\*])*t
```

Or this

```
>\s*a([`"\*])*l([`"\*])*p([`"\*])*h([`"\*])*a([`"\*])*b([`"\*])*e([`"\*])*t\s*<
```

**Edit**

Sorry forgot to escape *

Comment: `*` has no special meaning in a character class and doesn't need any escapes there. And why use capturing groups everywhere?

Comment: @Qtax I'm not perfect at regex. You might do a suggestion.

Comment: @Oybek he means that `[\`"\*]` can be `[\`"*]` because `*` is interpreted literally inside the char class (the brackets)

Comment: the problem is that any of the special chars can appear anywhere, this works in perl , but will not use perl (C or PHP):
$astring =~ s/["*`]//g; $astring =~ s/&Verbar;//g; if ($astring =~ /$pattern/i)
where $pattern is "<hw>alphabet</hw>"

Answer (score 0):

One I got that works for the cases you listed:

```
/<[a-zA-Z]+>al"*\**pha\**\"*b\"*e`*t<\/[a-zA-Z]+>/i
```

Check out http://www.rubular.com/. It's got a live test of regular expressions.

Comment: I think you *probably* were too literal in interpreting the question..the position of those special chars are *probably* just examples and any one of them can appear anywhere between the letters..

Comment: I also have a sneaking suspicion "alphabet" is just an example word and regex will be applied to any word... I know OP didn't say this but just sayin'...

Comment: that is correct any special char can appear between the letters, that's what is making this a little bit more complicated